# org.apache.catalina.ServerFactory.getServer() equivalent in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7

What is the equivalent of `org.apache.catalina.ServerFactory.getServer()` in Tomcat 7 or what would be the best way to retrieve `org.apache.catalina.Session` instances ?

Here is a sample code that used to work on Tomcat 6.0:

```
public List<org.apache.catalina.Session> findActiveSessions() throws ServiceException {
    StandardEngine engine = (StandardEngine) ServerFactory.getServer().findService("Catalina").getContainer();
    StandardContext  context = (StandardContext) engine.findChild(engine.getDefaultHost())
        .findChild(ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getContextPath()); 
    List<org.apache.catalina.Session> list = new ArrayList<org.apache.catalina.Session>();
    for (org.apache.catalina.Session session : context.getManager().findSessions()) {
        list.add(session);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can look it up via its management registration..

```
import javax.management.*;
import org.apache.catalina.Server;

MBeanServer mBeanServer = MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null).get(0);
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina", "type", "Server");
Server server = (Server) mBeanServer.getAttribute(name, "managedResource");
```

Obviously that code is devoid of error checking but is functional.

Comment: for embedded tomcat 7, it will be: new ObjectName("Tomcat", "type", "Server");

Comment: I grapped "port" directly because I did not have Server on the path (nor do I want it)