# Is it possible to enable JMX in embedded Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, jmx

I would like to access `Server` and `Connector`s from within my webapp.  Furthermore, I need to launch this webapp from embedded Tomcat.  Here is how I boot tomcat:

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(port);
StandardServer server = (StandardServer) tomcat.getServer();
server.addLifecycleListener(new AprLifecycleListener());
tomcat.addWebapp("/", webapp.getAbsolutePath());
tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
```

When I use the [typical example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7968752/207161) for accessing the Server via JMX[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7968752/207161):

```
import javax.management.*;
import org.apache.catalina.Server;

MBeanServer mBeanServer = MBeanServerFactory.findMBeanServer(null).get(0);
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Catalina", "type", "Server");
Server server = (Server) mBeanServer.getAttribute(name, "managedResource");
```

I get:

```
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=Server
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1094)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:662)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:638)
```

I assume this is because I am failing to bootstrap JMX somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like JMX is running fine, it's the name I used for lookup that is the problem.  Should have been:

```
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("Tomcat", "type", "Server");
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using the `PR_JVMOPTIONS`.  I got it resolved by using the following configuration parameters in my embedded tomcat installation service file.

```
set PR_JVMOPTIONS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false;-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false;-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9111
```