# Detect port of running grails app

Tags: tomcat, grails

I want to be able to deploy a .war file and detect which port the application is being served on. I have two grails' apps running within different tomcat instances, and ideally I would like to adapt the configuration of each app according to each specific tomcat instance. Each tomcat instance uses a different port, therefore detecting the port upon which the app is served means the app knows which tomcat instance the app is running in.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you give me feedback on my answer? Did it help?

Comment: Thanks Ralf, but I used a different solution. I needed the solution to work before the first request.

Comment: Note that in general "which port" may not have a single answer - you can configure several different connectors for the same tomcat, each on a different port number (e.g. SSL and non-SSL).

Answer (score 1):

I used an [externalized configuration](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) so that both grails apps would read a configuration relative to where each respective tomcat instance was started. By controlling from where each tomcat instance is started, then each grails app is configured appropriately. Therefore by placing the externalized configuration relative to the starting tomcat directory specific grail's app configuration is achieved!

Answer (score 0):

Is it enough to get the port when the first request arrives? Then this could help:

```
    println request.requestURL
    println request.request.request.request.connector.port
```

If not, take look at these tow pages - I guess they might help

[Get the server port number from tomcat with out a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867197/get-the-server-port-number-from-tomcat-with-out-a-request)

http://www.asjava.com/tomcat/how-to-get-tomcat-port-number-in-java/

always remember that oyu can use all the available java code in your grails application.

Comment: Caveat: If Tomcat is behind a proxy, the request values will be what the proxy uses - not the port/scheme/etc that Tomcat is using.