# Get JBoss HTTP Connector port in a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I've two web applications with one RESTFul service each one. In a service I need to call the second, for example, I Have StatusService and SomeService, depending on state SomeService do some different  action. So when I call SomeService its call StatusService to get the current state then do the action.

So, I used `reques.getServerPort()` in my SomeService to call my StatusService, I have something like this

```
 URL url = new URL("http://localhost:"+request.getServerPort()+"/app2/status");
```

It's working when I call the service directly from jboss .

But there are a Apache as a DMZ and only SomeService was externalized, so when I call SomeService via DMZ its try to call `http://localhost:80/app2/status` rather then `http://localhost:8080/app2/status`.

Is there another way to get the port?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `request.getLocalPort`

According to the javadocs it returns the port that the request was received on.

Comment: I tried getLocalPort and getServerPort both of them returned 80

Comment: OK : This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867197/get-the-server-port-number-from-tomcat-with-out-a-request   - but the whole thing looks scarey to me. If I was faced with this, my first approach would be the take the business logic from the StatusService and host it inside the same webapp as the SomeService lives. The just call it as any other java method. Is that a possibility?