# how to get baseuri of a rest web application while it is initializing

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I wanted to have base uri for my rest application at the time when servlet context get initializing. It is easily available at resource classes with the help of UriInfo. But I need it at the time my app is getting initialize. i am using jersey api (2.13).

Can any body suggest the way to get the base uri.

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

public RestApplication() {

// I Need The Base URi Here 
  }
}
```

**Or may be in this method**

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // I Need The Base URi Here 

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *base uri*?

Comment: HttpServletRequest is available in resource classes . but i need it in ServletContextListener or ResourceConfig or any where else which is being called at the time of initialisation of application by servlet container.

Comment: @KrrishRoy, please, give some code snippet to show the place you want to get base uri and where base uri should be obtained?

Comment: base uri : - protocol(https/http)://<host ip>:<port>/context path

Comment: @sphinks Source code added for your reference

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867197/get-the-server-port-number-from-tomcat-with-out-a-request

Comment: And, for the context path, use [`ServletContext.getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath--).

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin and what about the host ip and port and the protocol ?

Comment: See my comment above...

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin  thanks man. will check the approach.