# Setting Uri dynamically in HTTP Location Header

Tags: spring-integration

I implemented a Rest service that creates an Employee.  In the response message I  want to dynamically set the HTTP **Location** header with the newly created Employee resource Uri.

The below code is working fine and I am able to see the value in **Location** header as expected. However I have the Uri hardcoded in the EmpService and  I want it to be dynamic. How do I extract/pass Uri information to the EmpService bean?

**Config.xml**

---

```
 <int-http:inbound-gateway
     request-channel="httpPostChannel"
     reply-channel="responseChannel"
     path="/emp"
     supported-methods="POST"   
     message-converters="converters" 
     request-payload-type="com.samples.jaxb.Employee"/>

<int:service-activator ref="empService" method="post"   
                       input-channel="httpPostChannel"   output-channel="responseChannel"/>
```

### EmpService.java

```
public Message<Employee> post (Message<Employee> msg) {

    Employee emp = empDao.createEmployee(msg.getPayload());
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(emp)
                         .setHeader(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.LOCATION,  "http://localhost:8080/RestSample/emp/" + emp.getEmpId())
                         .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually even right now your URI is dynamic:

> "http://localhost:8080/RestSample/emp/" + emp.getEmpId()

OTOH you always can inject it via setter or `@Value` property during application start from some external property.

Or you even can do that extracting some property/header from the incoming `Message`.

However I guess you would like to know the host and port you are ran on.

The `host` you can know via `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`.

The `port` you can extract via an appropriate ServletContainer vendor API, e.g. for Tomcat: [Get the server port number from tomcat with out a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867197/get-the-server-port-number-from-tomcat-with-out-a-request).

With Spring Boot you can just use `@LocalServerPort`:

```
* Annotation at the field or method/constructor parameter level that injects the HTTP
* port that got allocated at runtime. Provides a convenient alternative for
* <code>&#064;Value(&quot;${local.server.port}&quot;)</code>.
```

Although... I guess this one should be enough for:

```
.setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.REQUEST_URL,
                        request.getURI().toString())
```

I mean that your incoming `Message` after `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` has header set. In my test case with Spring Boot and random Tomcat port it looks like:

```
"http_requestUrl" -> "http://localhost:64476/service/?name=foo"
```

Comment: I can get the complete Url from header as you mentioned. I was actually looking for any out-of-box option for getting the Uri till context path.  'http://localhost:8080/RestSample'

Comment: ??? "till context path" for me equals exactly to `http://localhost:8080`. Just because `/RestSample` is a context. All those parts (scheme, host, port) you can get exactly from the `URI` object. Please, demonstrate in your sample which part you would like to build dynamically.

Comment: Ok. What's wrong? Just do that in your code ! I still don't understand what you would like to get from us. You have headers, URI class to parse, UriComponentsBuilder and there are some other UriUtils around in Spring and Commons Http Client. On the other hand we always can do that just with code Java abilities!

Comment: Great! Does it mean that we can treat the question as closed?