# In the internals of an ContextListener how can I find out the port the Web App is running on

Tags: java, port, inetaddress, servletcontextlistener

In the internals of an ContextListener how can I find out the port the Web App is running on

I have a Java Web app project with JSP pages as frontend. The project implements a `ServletContextListener` to connect to the backend. This ContextListener accesses the database by instantiating an access class `DBQuery` in its `contextInitialized` method:

```
ServletContext ctx = contextEvent.getServletContext();
dbQuery = new DBQuery();
ctx.setAttribute("dbQuery", dbQuery);
```

The JSP pages then refer to this `DBQuery` object via

```
getServletContext().getAttribute("dbQuery");
```

and call the methods of `DBQuery` as they desire.

Now the problem: In the `DBQuery` class I need to do different things depending on which host and on which port the web app runs.

I found a way to determine  the *host name* in DBQuery:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

Strangely `InetAddress` does not seem to have a method to get the ***port number***. How can I find out in the `DBQuery` class on which the port the web app runs on?

Comment: Does this help?: https://gist.github.com/devcsrj/8c44193c510d4fb1cff3

Comment: @Steve Cool! Just tried it out and it seems to work not only in the context of `contextInitialized ` but even in my own `DBQuery` object. Thanks!

Comment: @Steve Do you want to write this up as an answer?

Comment: I didn't really add anything.  It's just that post, and that code was inspired by the SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867197/get-the-server-port-number-from-tomcat-with-out-a-request.  So maybe we should just close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Steve I disagree. The Solution might be similar, though the Question is quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7631480/steve)'s comment to look at a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/devcsrj/8c44193c510d4fb1cff3), I came up with the following adapted code which does exactly what was asked for:

```java
String port = "80";
try {
     MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
     Set<ObjectName> objs = mbs.queryNames( new ObjectName( "*:type=Connector,*" ),
             Query.match( Query.attr( "protocol" ), Query.value( "HTTP/1.1" ) ) );
     for ( ObjectName obj : objs ) {
         String scheme = mbs.getAttribute( obj, "scheme" ).toString();
         port = obj.getKeyProperty( "port" );
         break;
     }
} catch ( MalformedObjectNameException | UnknownHostException | MBeanException | AttributeNotFoundException | InstanceNotFoundException | ReflectionException ex ) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

So the main thing is to instantiate a `MBeanServer` and utilise its attributes.